# my way of solving the biology question

Tags: genetics, homework

[image]

Pure-breeding tall and pure-breeding short pea plants in the P generation were crossed as shown below. Based on the diagram below, one can assume that

a)short plant height is the dominant trait.

b)the F₂ generation will all be tall in height.

c)the alleles for plant height do not segregate during meiosis.

d)tall plant height is the dominant trait.

My answer: The answer is D becasue tall plant is the dominant trait because  A dominant trait is an inherited characteristic that appears in an offspring if it is contributed from a parent through a dominant allele

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. In particular, you are **required** to use the "homework" tag for ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions. (Note that "homework" can apply to questions even if they are not assigned as homework — for example because it "addresses a basic biology concept that may seem trivial to biology professionals".) ——— Thanks! 

Comment: can you help me if your good in biology,if my answer is correct ?@tyersome

Comment: and thanyou for the welcoming message,im glad to  join :)